# Meeting/Appointment template in MS Outlook 2010

Tags: microsoft-outlook, templates

I have been struggling to create a template a meeting invite template. The properties I set in the form do not appear in the template after I publish it. 
This is what I have done so far.

- Enabled Developer Options on the Ribbon.
- Created a form with these options

  - Appear as: Free
  - Request response: No
  - Reminder before: 2 days (2880 mins)
  - All day: Yes
- I published the form with a new name.

When I selected this form from New Items > Custom Forms > My Form, I can't see all the properties I mentioned set. For example, All Day Event comes unchecked, reminder is defaulted to 15 minutes, etc.

Is there something that I have missed?